# Printing the value of pointer to char in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I have this code:

```
main() {

    printf("enter the number of names: ");
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    getchar();

    char *p;
    p = malloc(n*LEN*sizeof(char));

    char *name = malloc(LEN*sizeof(char));

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        gets(name);
        strcpy((p + i), name);
        printf("%s \n", (p + i));
        strncpy(name, "", LEN);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        printf("%s\n", (p + i));

}
```

and I have trouble with printing the values of pointer ***p*** which is correct in the first loop but in the second loop the output is wrong.(LEN has defined as 15). Where is the problem?

Comment: p must be of type char**

Comment: What is `p + i`?

Comment: p = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));

Comment: The purpose of this code is unclear. Separate it out into functions and it will be far easier to understand.

Comment: @purec I can't use pointer to pointer. and if p has to change why the first loop's output is correct?

Comment: @doctorlove p is a pointer to a 2d array and p + i is the ith row of the array

Comment: then what do you want?

Comment: `p` (and `p+i`) is a pointer to a `char`

Comment: What is your platform? `gets` has been deprecated long time ago

Comment: @purec I have to read some names from input and do something with them. but in this step I can't read input.

Comment: use this at least: char* p[n];

Comment: or even this: char arr[n][LEN];

Comment: `gets` is **dangerous** and obsolete. Use something else like [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) or [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, all his program is dangerous.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve the code to get no warnings. Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Learn to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and the [GDB debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). And provide some [MCVE] in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `LEN` is the maximum string length, you allocated a big chunk of memory in which you want to put strings.

Then the `i`th string you should put at `strcpy((p + i*LEN), name);`

You should also take care the string is not too long and is terminated, so better use

```
    strncpy((p + i*LEN), name, LEN-1);
    *(p+i*LEN-1)= '\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

In this code

```
char *p;
p = malloc(n*LEN*sizeof(char));

char *name = malloc(LEN*sizeof(char));

int i;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    gets(name);
    strcpy((p + i), name);
    printf("%s \n", (p + i));
    strncpy(name, "", LEN);
}
```

you have a single `char` array, and put a "string" into the beginning when `i` is 0, e.g. "Hello".
When `i` is 1, if you use "world" as the next name, that's put into `p[1]`, so `p[0]` is still 'H', giving you `'HWorld'`.

You need a `char **` and `malloc` each `char *` inside th loop.
(Don't forget to `free` what you malloc later)